# Typescript: react-redux, react-i18next HOC type interference in a .JS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-i18next

I'm experiencing this really weird issue.

I have a TypeScript react project running, with react-redux and react-i18next setup (the @types packages are installed too).

Now I have the following scenario: In a TSX file, I import a component that is written in **js** not typescript, which is first run through the react-redux `connect` HOC and then through the react-i18next `withTranslation` HOC.

Now, when I want to render that component from the TSX file, I get an error when I try to assign actually existing props to that component, saying:

```
Type '{ name: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<WithTranslation, never> & WithTranslationProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<WithTranslation, never> & WithTranslationProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

First of all, why is there a type check for a component coming from JS? Second, it get's even weirder, because if I rewrite that JS component to TSX and create all the necessary interfaces, etc. then it works without any errors.

Lastly, the weirdest thing about it all, is that when I only use one of the HOCs then I don't get the error either. So only with them combined. This is why I'm not filing an issue in GitHub because I don't know which package is causing it.

Here is the JS component causing the error:

```
import React from "react";
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class TranslatedReactClass extends React.PureComponent {
  static defaultProps = {
    lastName: "noClassLastName",
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.propertyStore);

    return (
      <div>
        Class {this.props.t("Contact")}: {this.props.name} {this.props.lastName}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const comp = connect(state => {
  return {
    propertyStore: state.properties,
  };
})(TranslatedReactClass);

export default withTranslation()(comp);
```

And here is the same component rewritten in TSX that doesn't throw any error:

```
import React from "react";
import { withTranslation, WithTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

interface Props extends WithTranslation {
  name: string;
  lastName?: string;
  propertyStore?: any;
}

class TranslatedReactClass extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    lastName: "noClassLastName",
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.propertyStore);

    return (
      <div>
        Class {this.props.t("Contact")}: {this.props.name} {this.props.lastName}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const comp = connect((state: any) => {
  return {
    propertyStore: state.properties,
  };
})(TranslatedReactClass);

export default withTranslation()(comp);
```

I'm on the following (latest) versions:

1. "react-redux": "^7.1.3"
2. "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.6"
3. "react-i18next": "^11.3.0"
4. "@types/react-i18next": "^8.1.0"
5. "typescript": "^3.7.3"

As a summary, my two questions are:

1. Why are there TS checks for JS files?
2. Why do the typings interfere, even though they work when used separately.

**EDIT:**

Literally just realized 1min after posting this question, that the @types/react-i18next package is deprecated and react-18next already provides its own typings. Uninstalling it didn't actually fix anything though.

**EDIT 2:**

I did find a workaround, but it doesn't explain the problems at all. If I first translate the component and THEN connect, I don't get TS errors from **JS** files. The odd thing is, that I have to do the exact opposite for **TSX** files, otherwise, I get TS errors again.